# Complete a basis 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the space of 3x3 anti symmetric matrix 
And $S$ the subspace given by:

$$S = \left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}0 & r & a  \\ -r & 0 & t \\ -s & -t & 0 \end{bmatrix} \mbox{ such that } r+t=3s \right\rbrace $$

I have to find a space $S’$ Such that $S\oplus S’=V$

I have determined a basis B for S And since dimS= 2 the dimS’=1

If  I find one single element of S’, it’s enough to expand B to a basis for V.
How can I find a element of S’?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you want an s in the upper right hand corner of your matrix.

Once that is fixed, it should be clear that if you have 3 parameters you should have 3 basis vectors to cover the set of $3\times 3$ anti-symmetric matrices.

But then you have an additional constraint $r+t = 3s$  This takes us down to needing only two vectors.

Find any two that satisfy the constraint, and are independent from one another.  i.e. $r = 3s$ and $t = 3s$

$\begin{bmatrix} 0&3&1\\-3&0&0\\-1&0&0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1\\0&0&3\\-1&-3&0 \end{bmatrix}$  This gives us our basis for $S$

What about $S'$?  Anything independent from $S$ (and in $V$) will suffice.

$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$